# Trying project exemple "HelloAR", build succeed but nothing shows on the phone

Tags: c#, android, windows, unity-game-engine, arcore

i'm new to Unity and ARCore and i am trying to lauch the ARCore exemple project, but nothing is showing on my phone.

I'm using the **Unity 2018.2.2f1** and **ARcore v1.4**, but i had the exact same problem when i used the previous version (**2018.2.1f1** and **1.3**).
I run Unity on Windows 10.

Here is what i did :

- I create a new project named "AR"
- I add the " **arcore-unity-sdk-v1.4.0** " package
  **Assets > Import Package > Custom Package** ...
  And select " **arcore-unity-sdk-v1.4.0** "
- I select " **All** " to import all the package, then " **Import** "
- I have now 3 **CS0619** errors :
  [...] `error CS0619: 'UnityEngine.Network' is obsolete:`
  [...] `error CS0619: 'UnityEngine.Network.player' is obsolete:` [...] `error CS0619: 'UnityEngine.NetworkPlayer.ipAddress' is obsolete:` [...]
- I correct them by following thoses instructions
  https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/197
- I have now 1 **CS0618** warning, on 5 different files :
  [...] `warning CS0618: 'UnityEditor.Build.IPreprocessBuild' is obsolete: 'Use IPreprocessBuildWithReport instead'` [...]
  So i use " `IPreprocessBuildWithReport` " on the 5 different files
  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.OnPreprocessBuild.html
- 1 warning is still remaning, an other **CS0618**
  [...] `warning CS0618: 'UnityEngine.ScreenOrientation.Unknown' is obsolete:` [...]
  I simply replaced " [...] `ScreenOrientation.Unknown` " by " [...] `ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation` "
- Now that i don't have any errors or warning left, i continue to follow the ArCore Tutorial
  https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android
  (I am now at the "Open the sample scene" part)
- So i double clic on "**HelloAR**"
  **Assets > GoogleARCore > Examples > HelloAR > Scenes > HelloAR**
- I keep following the tutorial (Configure build settings)
- I when to **File > Build Settings to open the Build Settings window**
- Select **Android** and click **Switch Platform**
- **Player Settings > Other Settings > Multithreaded Rendering** : Disable
- **Player Settings > Other Settings > Package Name** : com.Help.HelloAR
- **Player Settings > Other Settings > Minimum API Level** : Android 7.0 'Nougat' (API level 24)
- **Player Settings > Other Settings > Target API Level** :  Android 7.0 'Nougat' (API level 24)
- **Player Settings > XR Settings > ARCore Supported** : Enable
- Now that everything is ready, i enable developer options and USB debugging on my phone (Samsung S8+, Android version : 8.0.0), connect it to my computer and go to **File > Build Settings > Build And Run**.
- Save the apk to my computer.
- But when i launch the application on my phone, the only thing i get is this :
  https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/32/2/1533648381-ar-error.jpg
  (The camera is allowed to be used with the application)
  (I also tried to " **Build** ", and then copy the apk to my phone, it does the same thing)

But the "fun" part, is the fact that, if i go back on Unity, delete the scene "HelloAR" and start to put 3D objects in front of the camera, i will still have this grey and blue image (sky texture) when i build the project. Doesn't mater what modification i do i will still have it.

Does anyone know where this problem comes from and maybe how to fix it ?
Can you think of anything i could try ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Build Settings? Maybe you forgot to add the HelloAR scene to it or to set it as the first scene.

Comment: I was indeed the problem ...
I corrected it and it is now working !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same exact issue, then I finally noticed that I was exporting the sample scene that unity defaults to. Did you check to see if you were in fact exporting the HelloAR scene for your build?

Comment: Indeed i wasn't building the right scene, to solve this :
- I went to **File > Build Settings**
- At the top of the window i disabled **Scenes/SampleScene**
- Clicked on " **Add Open Scenes** "
- And Enable " **GoogleARCore/Exemples/HelloAR/Scenes/HelloAR** "

Thank you so much for your help !